# R - como usar arquivos .xlsx e .csv com url do onedrive

Tags: r, onedrive

Gostaria de substituir o nome do arquivo para um link que baixasse o arquivo diretamente do onedrive. Minha intenção seria poder compartilhar com alguém apenas o script do R e ela pudesse rodar direto sem necessidade de ter que enviar diretamente os arquivos utilizados.

```
library(readxl)

base <- read_excel(**"tabela5938 pib.xlsx"**, col_names = c('Codigo', 'Municipio', 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016))
```

Answer (score 2):

Entre no OneDrive e no menu de contexto do arquivo pegue a opção "Embed". Irá gerar algo como:

```
<iframe src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243&resid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243%21177&authkey=AAbiQULpERX5A_I" width="98" height="120" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Copie o link e substitua *embed* por *download*: `https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=...`. Se a função que for usar para ler o arquivo tiver suporte para URL, use o link direto, caso contrário baixe e leia:

```
# CSV de exemplo no meu OneDrive
link.csv <- "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243&resid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243%21177&authkey=AAbiQULpERX5A_I"

> read.csv(link.csv)
  letra numero
1     A      1
2     B      2
3     C      3
4     D      4
```

Ou, baixando para um arquivo temporário primeiro:

```
link.xls <- "https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243&resid=E8F4DCBDA1CF1243%21178&authkey=AJMJUl3aej0ZnAk&em=2"

temp <- tempfile()
download.file(link.xls, temp)
readxl::read_xlsx(temp)
```